# PHP join 2 arrays of same key value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I'm wondering how to solved this. I have 3(three) arrays that contained nested values in the "data" key like this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "status" => "Terkirim"
    "warna" => "lightgreen"
    "data" => array:12 [
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 3
      7 => 0
      8 => 0
      9 => 0
      10 => 0
      11 => 0
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "status" => "Selesai"
    "warna" => "lightblue"
    "data" => array:12 [
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 3
      7 => 0
      8 => 0
      9 => 0
      10 => 0
      11 => 0
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "status" => "Selesai"
    "warna" => "lightblue"
    "data" => array:12 [
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 0
      7 => 1
      8 => 0
      9 => 0
      10 => 0
      11 => 0
    ]
  ]
]
```

My problem is how to join the "data" just if the "status" is the same?, or sum the the value if it already exists on the same index key, this is what I want to achieve:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "status" => "Terkirim"
    "warna" => "lightgreen"
    "data" => array:12 [
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 3
      7 => 0
      8 => 0
      9 => 0
      10 => 0
      11 => 0
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "status" => "Selesai"
    "warna" => "lightblue"
    "data" => array:12 [
      0 => 0
      1 => 0
      2 => 0
      3 => 0
      4 => 0
      5 => 0
      6 => 3
      7 => 1 <== the joined value 
      8 => 0
      9 => 0
      10 => 0
      11 => 0
    ]
  ]  
]
```

Any helps would be appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
    $joinedArray = [];
    for ($initialArray as $array) {
        if (array_key_exists($array['status'], $joinedArray) {
            for ($joinedArray['data'] as $key, $dataElement) {
                 $joinedArray['data'][$key] = $dataElement + $array['data'][$key];
            }
        } else {
             $joinedArray[$array['status']] = $array;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works with little modifications, you safe my day :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce()` to summarize the array into an associative array. Use `array_values()` to convert the associative array into a simple array.

```
$arr = //Your array
$result = array_values(array_reduce($arr, function($c, $v){
    if ( !isset( $c[ $v['status'] ] ) ) $c[ $v['status'] ] = $v;
    else foreach( $c[ $v['status'] ]['data'] as $key => &$val ) $val += $v['data'][$key];
    return $c;
}, array()));

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => Terkirim
            [warna] => lightgreen
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 3
                    [7] => 0
                    [8] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                    [10] => 0
                    [11] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => Selesai
            [warna] => lightblue
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 3
                    [7] => 1
                    [8] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                    [10] => 0
                    [11] => 0
                )

        )

)
```